# Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in AuthComponent.php on line 781

Tags: cakephp-2.5

> Error: Cannot unset string offsets
>   File: /var/www/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php
>   Line: 781

Code:

`if (isset($this->request->data['User'])) {
                $this->Auth->login();
}`

Any idea why this error happens?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the AppController.php

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ),
        'authError' => 'You must be logged in to view this page.',
        'loginError' => 'Invalid Username or Password.',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
        )
    )
);
```

authenticate needs to be

```
'authenticate' => array(
    'Form' => array(
        'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',
    )
)
```